# Any solution to have such a http relay or proxy

Tags: http, proxy, intranet

3 PCs A, B, C.

A: windows PC (within intranet, can reach B but blocked to C)
B: linux PC (within intranet, can reach A, C and access internet through proxy server at PC C)
C: proxy server (within intranet, could reach / proxy the traffic from/to internet)

I have no root account on PC B. I want a program to run at PC B (as a common user not root) to help me access Internet at PC A.

Any solutions or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH can do it.

Run `sshd` as a user on PC B (if it's not already running), then use PuTTy on PC A to tunnel through it (opening a SOCKS proxy on a local PC A port that funnels the traffic through the tunnel).